# ASIHttpRequest and core data thread safe

Tags: multithreading, core-data, asihttprequest

I use ASIHTTPRequest to get something from a server Asynchronously, and in callback I save the data in Core Data, I'm not sure, if I use "startAsynchronous" method, it runs in another thread, how does it affect the core data's thread safety? Thanks!

update:
after I start connection by calling startAsynchronous, in requestDidFinish: callback, which thread is it running in? Is it safe to perform some core-data operation in it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the ASIHTTPRequest delegate methods are run on the main thread by default (even in asyncronous requests), so it is safe to perform core-data operations.